# Booting directly into app: remove console prompt

Tags: boot, raspbian-stretch, plymouth

I try to quietly boot into a qt app on a raspberry 3 running raspian stretch. In my `/boot/cmdline.txt` I have

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty3 root=PARTUUID=02e50ed3-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet  loglevel=0 logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0 splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

with a custom plymouth splash screen. My qt app is started via systemctl (with `WantedBy=multi-user.target` in its `.service` file). Everything works nearly perfectly, but before my app is running, for approximately two seconds the console prompt

```
pi@raspberry:~/
```

is displayed above the plymouth splash screen. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service `getty@tty1.service` is responsible for this.

Try

```
systemctl disable getty@tty1.service
```